# can't install android studio in windows because of it can't download sdk

Tags: android, android-studio

hey guys I'm trying to install android studio on windows 10 for 3 days but all the time I'm getting the same error that is: Noting to do! Android Sdk id up to date. Sdk emulator directory is missing.
on the other hand, it doesn't make any Android file in user/AppData/local for Sdk at all. I really don't know what to do anymore please help me. the link of image of the error is -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFj7e.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo. Need a good proxy / vpn and then try again

Comment: thanks man, but do I need to remove it and then use a proxy or vpn and reinstall it? or I can fix it without reinstallation?

Comment: No need for reinstallation. have a look here https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod

Comment: Just in case, from File menu --> click "Invalidate cache and restart"